# How can I prevent users from starting a game level activity when that level is completed?

Tags: android, android-activity

Simple question, though I couldn't find anything related on SO.
I'm developing an android game and just added the score. Each game level is one activity, and each completed level adds an amount of score to the total. I would like to **forbid game level activity from starting again after that level is completed**, to prevent users from adding score over same level again.

I apologize for my poor english. Hopefully, I made myself understood.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you pass your score to next activity ?

Comment: so same as you are storing your score data and reuse in future you can store user name and use for more task. this is true if i getting you is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sharedpreferences to save a variable that will persist as long as your app is installed.
I would save a number this way, telling you what level the player has reached/completed.
You can read more [here on the android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)